# How can I know why my post was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, undelete

When a post is deleted, the following message appears

> deleted by (user)♦ 2 days ago
>   Why was your post deleted? See the faq.

Anyway, if I don't find the faq clear enough, what should I do?

Is there a way to contact (user) directly and ask for a clarification?

Or I should "undelete" (vote to restore the post)? I don't even know why I see the undelete button, since I have a low reputation score...

Comment: Ask here. What did you not understand?

Comment: Normally, there's a good reason posts are deleted, e.g. when they're of terribly low quality, or absolutely off-topic (in the case of questions), or answers *not* answering the question. You can try to fix the post, then flag it for attention to have it undeleted. But why not post the contents of this deleted post here and ask for the reason?

Comment: You can always ask here, just post a link to the post.

Comment: thank you. here is my post http://stackoverflow.com/a/10354030/1136458 (question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8792148/1136458 ). Maybe I'll open a new discussion if this happens again for an important response. In this case I am just curious!

Comment: Your answer says: *I'm just expanding Eugen Rieck comment, but I have not the comment privilege, so here is my comment.*.  Ergo, it's a comment, not an answer, and you don't have comment privileges yet.  In other words, you subverted the system by posting a comment as an answer.  A moderator deleted it; that's why you don't see an "undelete" option, otherwise people could just routinely undo moderator decisions.

Comment: actually I do see the "undelete" option! I haven't clicked it, though, so I don't know if it is really enabled for me.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how it was deleted.

Posts can be deleted by several users of sufficient reputation (and consequently undeleted, if deleted in error). Posts can also  be deleted by diamond moderators, who respond to flags by the community to remove posts that do not meet our faq guidelines.

I'd suggest your best bet is to have a look at the FAQ and see if there's anything in there that looks like it might be the cause, i.e.:

- Link only answers.
- Product advertising.
- Duplicating other answers.
- Old questions.
- Not answering the question (it *may* have been converted to a comment).

And so on. If you still feel having looked through all of those it was in error, you can raise a post here on meta. I would suggest if you have a link to the question or answer you're referring to, you edit your post and we can then explain :)

Comment: Ok thank you. I didn't know if it was ok to open a discussion here for a specific question. Anyway, my post was only a response to a comment, it's not a big matter. I found a question because I was having the same issue described, I followed the indications given in the comments and I wrote the very last step which was missing. The question was 5 months old, but it was not closed, and I thought other people could search for the same solution as it had just happened to me. (I'll add the link in question above)

Comment: @laika if it was a response to a comment, it'll have been deleted and converted to a comment (probably). All you need to do to avoid that is hit 50 rep, then you can comment on anything. In the mean time, suggested edits might be one way to add in missing details (plus, you get +2 rep for each approved suggested edit) :)

Comment: good to know the edit option!

Comment: @laika yep. To have the best chance of getting your edits approved, look for all the problems (spelling, formatting etc) you can fix in a post if you use it, without changing what the original author meant to say. That way there'll hardly ever be any issues getting edits approved :)

Comment: @laika: If you found a solution to the problem described in the question, why not write it up as a stand-alone answer? Then others can upvote it and you'll earn some rep. :) It's OK to repeat something already mentioned in a comment -- comments are not answers, and answers are generally expected to be as self-contained as possible.